# variable expansion within command substitution over SSH bash 4.X

Tags: bash, ssh, quoting, variable-substitution, command-substitution

I want to do this `ssh ${w100user}@web100 'ls -l "$(grep "${1}" /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd|cut -d':' -f6)"'`

Which obviously performs an ssh session to  server web100 as w100user and then greps for the script's first argument "$1" in the file pureftp.passwd, grabbing the 6th field which should be that user's home directory and will then list the contents with a long listing of that user's home directory.  I can't seem to get $1 to expand properly before in the command substitution over SSH.  I tried multiple quoting methods including '$( "$1" command...)' and at this point it's just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it in a `$LC_xxx` variable which is one that `ssh` often passes across:

```
LC_MY_USER=$1 ssh "${w100user}@web100" '
    ls -l "$(grep -F "$LC_MY_USER" /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd|cut -d: -f6)"'
```

Or maybe more robustly:

```
LC_MY_USER=$1 ssh "${w100user}@web100" '
    ls -l -- "$(awk -F: "/\$1 == ENVIRON[\"LC_MY_USER\"] {print \$6; exit}
      " /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd)"'
```

(assuming you want to check `$1` against the first field in that password file).

You could do:

```
ssh "${w100user}@web100" '
    ls -l "$(grep -F "'"$1"'" /etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.passwd|cut -d: -f6)"'
```

to have the local shell expand `$1`, but beware that it's potentially dangerous as it's interpreted as shell code by the remote shell (think for instance of `$1` being `$(rm -rf /)`). So you'd have to sanitize `$1` first.